# Android UI Images vs Layout xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering what your thoughts are on which is the better strategy when designing UI for android devices.

Which do you preffer:

> 1. Setting the size of elements in the XML files, for each denisty (and size when needed), using only one set of images (xxhdpi images) which will scale down when needed.
>
>    Pros - smaller apps (less resources)
>         Less work on images for UI people.
>
>    Cons - more work on XML files (a whole lot sometimes)
> 2. Create images for each denisty (and size if neede) using Wrap_content most of the time.
>
>    Pros - Only one set of XML layout files.
>
>    Cons - more images and larger sized apk.
>         more work on images for UI people.

What other approaches are you using?

Thanks!

Comment: You can still use wrap content with the first approach. Android will pre-scale the images to the appropriate size before measuring the Views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what Android is doing when it scales images that you do not provide. The [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) state:

> By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) and Nine-Patch drawables (.9.png files) so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device. For example, if your application provides bitmap drawables only for the baseline, medium screen density (mdpi), then the system scales them up when on a high-density screen, and scales them down when on a low-density screen. This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps. To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities.

All this means is that if you do not provide alternate density versions of images, Android will fill in the missing ones (created and the correct proportional size) using the ones you have provided, but at the cost of some quality of the image, since Android is not going to scale an image as well as say Photoshop. If you are concerned with application size, you can consider if the loss of image quality from omitting certain density versions is an acceptable tradeoff in order to make your .apk smaller.

So, #1 and #2 can both use `wrap_content`, and neither has to set the size of an image manually, unless the image needs to be larger or smaller than the original size (which in that case you should just create the image at the right size). #1 also does not and should not require more layout work. And for #2, saving an image at several sizes is not very much extra work at all.

I personally follow these rules:

1. Create images for every density (except `ldpi` / `tvdpi` - [too few devices](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), I'm ok with the image quality loss on them).
2. Use `wrap_content` and `match_parent` as needed with images.
3. Only use `dp` for images downloaded at runtime, where size cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Great answer, but why then creating images for every density and not only xhdpi? (or xxhdpi)

Comment: @UdiI I prefer to have my images look as good as possible. Creating them using Photoshop looks better than letting Android resize them. **"This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps. To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities."** This is ultimately your decision, if you are ok with the lower quality of your images at lower densities, then you can only add the `xxhdpi` version of them.

Answer (score 0):

my choice is a mixed one. I create differet images for those which are complex and has a chance of being abnormal for automatic compression. But for usual images I only used the first approach.